# Unrecognized Token C/C++(7) Error in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-code, visual-c++

**Unrecognized Token C/C++(7) Error in Visual Studio Code**

I am unsure why I am receiving these error messages; I am trying to compile c++11 code on VSC.

Please help? Thank you

[see code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCOW6.png)

For example, on Line 7 there is an "Unrecognized Token C/C++(7) Error" :

```
string str = “fine”;
```

Comment: You have some fancy unicode quotes, instead of the regular ones.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat , oh my gosh, thank you!

Comment: I wrote the code in MAC notes and when copied from there got this error. Kept scratching my head on what went wrong. This is spot on. It added some extra unnecessary white spaces in some unicode which are not visible, but removing them solved my issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you are using fancy unicode quotes. It may happen when you copy code from some messenger. Messengers often replace original quotes to that type of quotes.